# Removing snap without removing ubuntu-server-minimal

Tags: apt, server, snap

OS: Ubuntu Server 22.04

Friend has been setting up a server and he does not need snap so he wanted to remove it, but once he tried removing it it showed ubuntu-server-minimal as a dependency.

```
user@server:~$ sudo apt remove snapd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
        squashfs-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
        snapd ubuntu-server-minimal
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 89.6 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Is there a way to NOT remove the meta package? And if he successfully removes snapd without the meta package will it be re-added when the meta package upgrades (if that's a thing)? (Will blocking it from apt (like linux mint does) fix that?)

Comment: I'm not using *jammy* or 20.04, but for my own release a CLI query shows `Depends: apparmor, apport, apt, bcache-tools, btrfs-progs, cloud-init, cryptsetup, dbus, lvm2, mdadm, multipath-tools, netbase, ntfs-3g, open-iscsi, pollinate, snapd, ssh-import-id, sudo, systemd, systemd-sysv, ubuntu-drivers-common, ubuntu-release-upgrader-core, udev, xfsprogs` as the depends for `ubuntu-server-minimal` package... which is what will occur. If you remove `snapd` & leave `ubuntu-server-minimal` package installed; you'll have the *depends* rule met via re-install of `snapd`  (for my release anyway)

Comment: That's one question answered, wasn't sure if apt reinstalled dependencies when their main package was gone. I find it pretty dumb that Canonical decided to include a meta package for server that _REQUIRES_ some packages to be installed. Some might not want these packages installed anyways for a light install or such.

Comment: It's not dumb from their point of view, because they want to force you to use snaps.

Comment: If Friend wants the Ubuntu experience that the developers intend, then snapd is part of that experience. The use of that easy path is NOT required. Friend is welcome to do their homework and specify their own custom list of services/top-level-packages. Friend's Ubuntu system will happily do either alternative. There might be LOTS of packages they don't need installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A meta package is a "shopping list" that has a number of packages as dependencies, so it allows to install a certain configuration, e.g. minimal server, ubuntu desktop, etc., by installing a single package. A package can only remain on the system if all its dependencies are on the system. For `ubuntu-server-minimal`, `snapd` is a hard depencency, in contrast to the meta packages for the desktop, where `snapd` is a recommended package, not a dependency.

Remove one of dependencies will remove the metapackage: that is how the APT system is defined by its core. You only remove the metapackage - you will not remove other dependencies or recommended packages that were installed with that metapackage. Since these dependencies or recommended packages are are marked as "manually installed", they also will not be removed by a `sudo apt autoremove` after the metapackage is removed.

> Is there a way to NOT remove the meta package?

**No**, because `snapd` is a dependency. One would need to build a custom metapackage, that does not contain that specific dependency for having an equivalent metapackage without snapd. IF `snapd` were a recommended package, you could remove it without removing the metapackage.

> And if he successfully removes snapd without the meta package will it be re-added when the meta package upgrades (if that's a thing)? (Will blocking it from apt (like linux mint does) fix that?)

As explained, this can/will not happen with the `ubuntu-server-minimal` package. It will be removed. If `snapd` installation is blocked, you will not be able to reinstall `ubuntu-server-minimal`: there will be an error because one of the dependencies cannot be installed.

Comment: Guess I'll just tell them to use a different distro...

Comment: @xproot, to be clear, there's no harm done in removing this meta package. All it means is that you haven't satisfied all of its dependencies-- it _must_ be removed. Removing it means nothing, though-- it's only a meta package.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not using *jammy* or 20.04, but for my own release a CLI query (`apt-cache show depends ubuntu-server-minimal`) shows

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:/de2900/ubuntu_64/slow_boot$   apt-cache show depends ubuntu-server-minimal
Package: ubuntu-server-minimal
Architecture: amd64
Version: 1.487
Priority: optional
Section: metapackages
Source: ubuntu-meta
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 53
Depends: apparmor, apport, apt, bcache-tools, btrfs-progs, cloud-init, cryptsetup, dbus, lvm2, mdadm, multipath-tools, netbase, ntfs-3g, open-iscsi, pollinate, snapd, ssh-import-id, sudo, systemd, systemd-sysv, ubuntu-drivers-common, ubuntu-release-upgrader-core, udev, xfsprogs
Recommends: needrestart, unattended-upgrades
Filename: pool/main/u/ubuntu-meta/ubuntu-server-minimal_1.487_amd64.deb
Size: 2622
```

as the depends for `ubuntu-server-minimal` package... which is what will occur. If you remove `snapd` & leave `ubuntu-server-minimal` package installed; you'll have the *depends* rule met via re-install of `snapd`

The CLI enquiry shows for me my *kinetic* release, and  https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-server-minimal shows that for *jammy* too.